# Retrieving records from an ABPerson object

Tags: macos, cocoa, abaddressbook

I'm trying to get the Country from a ABPerson object in Cocoa.

What I do is:

```
NSString *country = [person valueForProperty:kABAddressCountryKey];
```

I get this in the console:

> -[ABPerson valueForProperty:Country] - unknown property. This warning will be displayed only once per unknown property, per session.

Getting the persons' organizationName(`kABOrganizationProperty`), firstName (`kABFirstNameProperty`) and lastName (`kABLastNameProperty`) works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the key `kABAddressCountryKey` implies it represents a value of an address. As person can have multiple addresses (represented as dictionaries) you have to loop the addresses to get the country:

```
ABMultiValueRef addressesRef = ABRecordCopyValue(personRef, kABPersonAddressProperty);

for (int i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(addressesRef); i++)
{
    CFDictionaryRef oneAddressRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(addressesRef, i);
    NSString *country = CFRetain(CFDictionaryGetValue(oneAddressRef, kABPersonAddressCountryCodeKey));
    // Do fancy things with country...
    CFRelease(country);
    CFRelease(oneAddressRef);
}

CFRelease(addressesRef);
```

Haven't finally tested it, but it should work that way. Also consider the [Core Foundation Memory Management](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/&ei=DvMAUqfIGonMsgbEmICACg&usg=AFQjCNE17Vky3OsDv6jcESIVf1Hu6qB8aw&sig2=H8xG-UC3zYTv3AISIVjX6Q&bvm=bv.50310824,d.Yms).

Comment: Thanks for pushing me in the right direction. I had a look at Apples documentation here as well: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AddressBook/Tasks/AccessingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001023-CJBDFIGI